# Does this count as suicide?

Tags: fiqh, sin, death, jahannam, suicide

Does it count as suicide if one asks someone else to kill them since they can't do it themself? Would that person still go to hell?

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt, as the intention is the same (i.e. ending his own life).. Either by the hands of oneself or any other tool/hand.. recall what prophet (Peace be upon him) said:

> إنما الأعمال بالنّيّات

That means: Acts are judged by what we meant to accomplish through them.